# Is there any way to install pandas on pypy2-v5.8.0-win32?

Tags: pandas, pypy

Windows 7 64bit.I had install numpy 1.10.0 successfully via.
`pypy -m pip install git+https://bitbucket.org/pypy/numpy.git`
Then,I tried three method(pip+git,pip,easy_install) to install pandas,however,**all failed,why**?

**method**:
`pip install git+https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas.git`

```
failed reason:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pypy2-v5.8.0-win32\lib-python\2.7\logging\__init__.py", line 895, in
emit
    stream.write(fs % msg)
  File "D:\pypy2-v5.8.0-win32\site-packages\pip\_vendor\colorama\ansitowin32.py"
, line 141, in write
    self.write_and_convert(text)
  File "D:\pypy2-v5.8.0-win32\site-packages\pip\_vendor\colorama\ansitowin32.py"
, line 169, in write_and_convert
    self.write_plain_text(text, cursor, len(text))
  File "D:\pypy2-v5.8.0-win32\site-packages\pip\_vendor\colorama\ansitowin32.py"
, line 174, in write_plain_text
    self.wrapped.write(text[start:end])
IOError: [Errno 12] Not enough space: '<stdout>'
Logged from file __init__.py, line 703
Command "D:\pypy2-v5.8.0-win32\pypy.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__fil
e__='c:\\users\\linwang\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-i1adus-build\\setup.py';f=get
attr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.clo
se();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\linwang\ap
pdata\local\temp\pip-6s0jzx-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externall
y-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/2636/sysstderr-cannot-write-big-string-on

Answer (score 0):

1. We no longer recommend using  https://bitbucket.org/pypy/numpy.git, as documented [here](https://pypy.org/download.html#installing-numpy) we now recommend using the upstream standard numpy repo.
2. Using upstream NumPy should install, but may crash.
3. Support for pandas is a work in progress, you should use the latest HEAD of [PyPy](http://buildbot.pypy.org/nightly/trunk/), cython, NumPy and Pandas as [work](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/wiki/cpyext_2_-_cython_and_pandas) is ongoing. We would love to get more feedback if you continue to have problems, we hang out on IRC at #pypy